# Return multiple elements using Lodash _.get?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this JavaScript object:

```js
const object = {
  categories: [
    {
      title: 'Category 1',
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 1', image: 'path/to/file-1.png' },
        { title: 'Item 2', image: 'path/to/file-2.png' },
        { title: 'Item 3', image: 'path/to/file-3.png' }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Category 2',
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 4', image: 'path/to/file-4.png' },
        { title: 'Item 5', image: 'path/to/file-5.png' },
        { title: 'Item 6', image: 'path/to/file-6.png' }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I was able to select only one item using Lodash's `_.get` method.

```js
_.get(object, 'categories[0].items[0].image')
// => "path/to/file-1.png"
```

But I need an array with all occurrences, not just from position 0. Something like this:

```js
_.get(object, 'categories[].items[].image')
// => ["path/to/file-1.png", "path/to/file-2.png", "path/to/file-3.png", "path/to/file-4.png", "path/to/file-5.png", "path/to/file-6.png"]
```

Is it possible to do it using Lodash?

If it's not possible, do you have any idea how to implement it?

**EDIT:** I'm looking for something like `_.get` from Lodash, where I can supply the "search schema" (path) as string. Obviously I know how to solve this with `map`, `reduce`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my implementation of a `flatGet` function that can handle arrays:

```js
const flatGet = (object, path) => {
  const p = path.match(/[^.\[\]]+/g)
    
  const getItem = (item, [current, ...path]) => {  
    if(current === undefined) return item
    
    if(typeof item !== 'object') return undefined
    
    if(Array.isArray(item)) return item.flatMap(o => getItem(o[current], path))
    
    return getItem(item[current], path)
  }
    
  return getItem(object, p)
}

const object = {"categories":[{"title":"Category 1","items":[{"title":"Item 1","image":"path/to/file-1.png"},{"title":"Item 2","image":"path/to/file-2.png"},{"title":"Item 3","image":"path/to/file-3.png"}]},{"title":"Category 2","items":[{"title":"Item 4","image":"path/to/file-4.png"},{"title":"Item 5","image":"path/to/file-5.png"},{"title":"Item 6","image":"path/to/file-6.png"}]}]}

var result = flatGet(object, 'categories.items.image')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to do with `flatMap`, no library required:

```js
const object = {
  categories: [
    {
      title: 'Category 1',
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 1', image: 'path/to/file-1.png' },
        { title: 'Item 2', image: 'path/to/file-2.png' },
        { title: 'Item 3', image: 'path/to/file-3.png' }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Category 2',
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 4', image: 'path/to/file-4.png' },
        { title: 'Item 5', image: 'path/to/file-5.png' },
        { title: 'Item 6', image: 'path/to/file-6.png' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const images = object.categories.flatMap(({ items }) => items.map(({ image }) => image));
console.log(images);
```

Or, with `reduce`:

```js
const object = {
  categories: [
    {
      title: 'Category 1',
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 1', image: 'path/to/file-1.png' },
        { title: 'Item 2', image: 'path/to/file-2.png' },
        { title: 'Item 3', image: 'path/to/file-3.png' }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Category 2',
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 4', image: 'path/to/file-4.png' },
        { title: 'Item 5', image: 'path/to/file-5.png' },
        { title: 'Item 6', image: 'path/to/file-6.png' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const images = object.categories.reduce((a, { items }) => {
  items.forEach(({ image }) => {
    a.push(image);
  });
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(images);
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it using loops/functions... I forgot to be clear that I need something like `_.get`, where I can supply the "search schema" as string.

Answer (score 1):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for these types of queries now. It's pretty powerful (once you wrap your head around it) and easy enough to use for basic stuff. Here is how you could solve your problem

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const object = { categories: [ { title: 'Category 1', items: [ { title: 'Item 1', image: 'path/to/file-1.png' }, { title: 'Item 2', image: 'path/to/file-2.png' }, { title: 'Item 3', image: 'path/to/file-3.png' } ] }, { title: 'Category 2', items: [ { title: 'Item 4', image: 'path/to/file-4.png' }, { title: 'Item 5', image: 'path/to/file-5.png' }, { title: 'Item 6', image: 'path/to/file-6.png' } ] } ] };

const r = objectScan(['categories[*].items[*].image'], { rtn: 'value' })(object);

console.log(r);
/* =>
 [ 'path/to/file-6.png', 'path/to/file-5.png', 'path/to/file-4.png',
   'path/to/file-3.png', 'path/to/file-2.png', 'path/to/file-1.png' ]
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

```
_([object]).flatMap("categories").flatMap("items").flatMap("image").value()
```

Full example:

```js
const _ = lodash; // const _ = require("lodash");

const object = {
  categories: [
    {
      title: 'Category 1',
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 1', image: 'path/to/file-1.png' },
        { title: 'Item 2', image: 'path/to/file-2.png' },
        { title: 'Item 3', image: 'path/to/file-3.png' }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Category 2',
      items: [
        { title: 'Item 4', image: 'path/to/file-4.png' },
        { title: 'Item 5', image: 'path/to/file-5.png' },
        { title: 'Item 6', image: 'path/to/file-6.png' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const result = _([object]).flatMap("categories").flatMap("items").flatMap("image").value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/lodash@4.17.21"></script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Here is my implementation which can handle `[]` path:

```js
const object = { categories: [ { title: "Category 1", items: [ { title: "Item 1", image: "path/to/file-1.png" }, { title: "Item 2", image: "path/to/file-2.png" }, { title: "Item 3", image: "path/to/file-3.png" } ] }, { title: "Category 2", items: [ { title: "Item 4", image: "path/to/file-4.png" }, { title: "Item 5", image: "path/to/file-5.png" }, { title: "Item 6", image: "path/to/file-6.png" } ] } ] };
const object2 = { categories: { title: "Category 1" } };

function flatGet(object, path) {
  const pathArray = path.split(".");
  while (pathArray.length > 0) {
    let pos = pathArray.shift();
    if (pos.includes("[]")) {
      pos = pos.slice(0, -2);
    }
    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
      object = object.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur[pos]), []);
    } else {
      object = object[pos];
    }
  }
  return object;
}

var res = flatGet(object, "categories[].items[].image"); // ["path/to/file-1.png", ...]
var res2 = flatGet(object2, "categories.title"); // "Category 1"
```

---

edited before:

Cause you need to get the `images` Array, `map` could help with it. Here is a simple one:

```js
_.map(object.categories[0].items, o => _.get(o, 'image'))

// if categories[0].items is not always there, just use another get:

_.map(_.get(object, 'categories[0].items'), o => _.get(o, 'image'))
```